# nilpotent mutiply invertible matrice is nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does nilpotent matrix A multiply invertible matrix P like that:
$P^{-1}AP$  will get me a nilpotent matrix?
I'm not sure about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left(P^{-1}AP\right)^n=P^{-1}A^nP\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Nilpotent means $A^k = 0.$ What is $(P^{-1}AP)^k?$ Try it for $k=2.$